# What is happening here when the else statement is not used?

Tags: java, if-statement

This is coding bat exercise: Java > Warmup-2 > stringX

What is the second block of code doing? Why does it produce the wrong answer?

```
public String stringX(String str) {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.substring(i , i+1).equals("x") && i != 0 && i != str.length()-1) {
            answer = answer + "";
        }
        else {
            answer = answer + str.substring(i , i + 1);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

vs

```
public String stringX(String str) {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.substring(i , i+1).equals("x") && i != 0 && i != str.length()-1) {
            answer = answer + "";
        }
        answer = answer + str.substring(i , i + 1);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block will run `else` only if the first `if` statement is **false**. `else` statement can only run if none of the above conditional statements returned true (`if` and `else if`). However the second block will run regardless of whether the first `if` statement true **or** false.

Check out this doc for further explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd block executes all the code shown and thus always takes the substring of answer